# Directly accessing a JSON element with a colon / special character in element Name with JQ

Tags: jq

I am trying to following the manual and examples out there and its not especially clear on how to handle colons element name if you want to specifically within a JQ output without outputting the entire structure.

```
Raw:{"UpdateResponseMessage":{"Header":{"com:TransactionID":"5e5b1750-7be7-11e8-886a-838029aca397","com:TimeStamp":"2018-06-29T21:57:08.549Z","com:SourceSystem":"Call","com:Status":"Success"}},"level":"info","message":"UpdateResponseMessage being sent.","timestamp":"2018-06-29T21:57:08.549Z"}
```

The output of `jq-win64 [.] test.log` is the following:

```
 [  {
"UpdateResponseMessage": {
  "Header": {
    "com:TransactionID": "5e5b1750-7be7-11e8-886a-838029aca397",
    "com:TimeStamp": "2018-06-29T21:57:08.549Z",
    "com:SourceSystem": "Call",
    "com:Status": "Success"
  }
},
```

]

I am attempting to call just "com:Status" and "com:TransactionID" but it either gives me a syntax error (INVALID_CHARACTER) or turns out no data "null" with everything I have tried.

The following outputs "null" for TransactionID and Status.

There were previous reports of people trying to figure out (issue [741](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/741), [745](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/745) with the suggestion to use `jq <x.json '.["key::name"]'`and similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427529/accessing-field-with-jq-that-contains-a-special-character-and-can-be-an-object-o) the above code for [JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089319/parsing-field-name-with-a-colon-in-json) as well as some variations have tried to follow the guidance but the [JQ manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons) has no examples specifically addressing this situation either.

The following at least doesn't error, but it doesn't output the values, just "NULL" for the two elements containing the ":" in their name.. if I add the ``` mark like I have in the commented out field I get "Invalid_Character" again.

```
             elif .UpdateResponseMessage then 
            # ( .UpdateResponseMessage .Header | [`.["com::TransactionID"]`] ) 
             ( .UpdateResponseMessage .Header | ["Response", `.["com::TransactionID"], .["com::Status"]] )
```

Output:

"Response","null","null"

But what I need is:

"Response","5e5b1750-7be7-11e8-886a-838029aca397","Success"

Comment: Can you update your input JSON to be syntactically right? As of now it ain't.  Use https://jsonlint.com/ to fix it

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494389/escape-field-name-in-jq-that-contains-and and the jq FAQ: `: How can I access the value of a key with hyphens or $ or other special characters in it? Why does .a.["$"] produce a syntax error?` (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#general-questions)